# I want to know how to use "pkl" and "npz" files in python. I could only get str from them

Tags: python, dataset, pickle

I need IMU dataset, So I have downloaded it from the following
https://dip.is.tuebingen.mpg.de/

The files are either "pkl" or "npz". So I looked for how to load it in python.
however, I can see only a "list" that contained a few "str" valuables.
I expected I would get some objects but it had only a few strings, also can't seem to be data.

```
with np.load("imu_own_test.npz") as f:
    file_list = f.files
    for item in file_list:
        print(type(item))
```

So I also tried encoding, because the "str" didn't seem to be the proper type of character.
But, didn't work.
I can see only these characters.
"x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfa~j\xbct\x93\x98?B>\xe8\xd9\xac\xfa\xac\xbf\xb8\x1e\x85\xebQ\xb8\xae\xbf\xfc\xa9\xf1\xd2Mbp?B\xcff\xd5\xe7j\x"

```
with open('01.pkl', 'r') as source_file:
    with open('02.csv', 'w+b') as dest_file:
        contents = source_file.read()
        dest_file.write(contents.encode('utf-16'))
```

How can I use it?

Comment: It's impossible to tell with certainty from a file extension what that file contains. There should be accompanying documentation to tell you what you want to know. That said, I'll guess that the extension `. pkl` is a `pickle` file. Try importing that module and calling `pickle. load()` on it. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Comment: Oh, thanks. I thought there was some way to figure out what was pickled in it. Then I would look over the documents.  Thanks again.

Comment: If it is a pickle file, then call `pprint.pprint()` on what `pickle.load()` gives you back. That is about as much self-description as you will be able to extract.